# Saving User sort DataGrid Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, web

I have a DataGrid in Silverlight which the User can sort. Now if the Data gets updated it goes back to standard sorting. Is there anyway I can easily implement it, that the user selected sorting stays?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways of doing that,

When Collection change ,
i.e.

```
 ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged +=(sender,args)=>
 {

   ReSort(); 
   /* You may trigger CollectionViewSource's populete event here  
       It can sort,filter ,group etc. 
    */

}
```

For CollectionViewSorting 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83906/Silverlight-4-Datagrid-Sorting-Grouping-Filtering

Another basically set Sort Member Path

```
    datePickerColumn.SortMemberPath = "Birthday";
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/06/10/sorting-data-in-the-silverlight-datagrid.aspx

hope helps.